# Angular with angular/cli - not able to find rxjs operator mergeDelayError

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I am currently happily working with **Angular (2.4.0)** and **angular/cli (1.0.0-rc1)**, using in many places the **RxJs** library. The entire installation is pretty standard (i.e. I have not personalized any config file).

Here my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sharewithfriends",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Now I have a point where I would like to use the `mergeDelayError` operator of `Observable`. Unfortunately the intellisense of VSCode can not find such operator.

Any suggestion about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operator `mergeDelayError` in RxJS**5** (which is the RxJS-Version used in Angular 2+)

It was implemented in RxJS4 though and is currently not mentioned on the [migrations-page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) - if you wish to use this in RxJS5 you should open a feature-request on the [github-page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues) or port it yourself and create a pull-request.

Comment: This operator (mergeDelayErro) is mentioned in node_modules/rx/ts/rx.d.ts . Does this mean anything?

Comment: the rx-package is "rxjs 4.x" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx) - it is also not listed in your package.json so it would be interesting to find out how it got in your node_modules-folder, probably through some sub-dependency from another module if you did not install it - however it is not really possible (and absolutely not adviced!) to use rxjs4 and rxjs5 in parallel as the two libraries have two completely different codebases

Answer (score 0):

The source code of RxJs found in this link [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/operator). Does not contain the mergeDelayError operator

So you will not get intellisense